# VSCode: opening one remote file using rcode closes another

Tags: visual-studio-code, remote-access

I recently started looking at VSCode as a possible substitute for Sublime 3 (I use Mac OS Sierra 10.13.1). I regularly work with code on a remote server, so I installed "rcode", following the steps in https://codepen.io/ginfuru/post/remote-editing-files-with-ssh.

Everything seemed to be working nicely, until I tried editing two files at the same time:

```
rcode file1.py
rcode file2.py
```

Each time I opened a new file from the remote server, the first one closed automatically, leaving me with just file2.py open.

This is really frustrating, since I need to go back and forth between them, and I can't find any information on this issue. I have the same problem using "rmate".

Has anyone else run into something similar and is there a work-around? I never had a problem working with multiple files in Sublime.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a perfect solution, but if you change `"workbench.editor.enablePreview"` to  `false` in your settings, rmate (and probably rcode) will open files in new tabs.

Comment: Workbench Editor: Enable preview v Controls whether opened editors show as preview Preview editors are reused until they are pinned (e.g. via double click or editing) and show up with an italic font style